# Add a constant to all values in a csv file for certainn columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file that contains columns

id,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,type

with numerical values in columns 1 to 7
I would like to open this file and add a constant to all values in those columns 1 - 7 for all rows. 
Any thoughts on how to do this? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add for example the constant `1` to all the values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

cols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

df[cols] = df[cols].add(1)
```

Change `1` in `add(1)` to whatever constant you want.

If you want to save your updated dataframe, use:

```
df.to_csv('filename_edited.csv')
```

Comment: what would i change if i wanted to appended this to the same file?

Comment: hmm doesnt seem to work, KeyError: '[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] not in index'

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your column names, try `cols = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']` instead (reading them in as strings). As for if you want it saved as the same file, use `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` (overwrite the original file)

Comment: sorry, one more thing i am stuck with if you dont mind. the code you suggested works but does add back in the other columns. how would i do this if i wanted to re join columns 1-7 with the others in the file but leave them unchanged?

Comment: Would you want them with different column names? like append the original 1-7 with `1_new`, `2_new`, etc?

Comment: nope the names the same. so just take out the columns i want to add too and then add it back to the file appended and with the same other columns with values kept the same

Comment: instead of `df[cols] = ...`, use `df = pd.concat((df,df[cols].add(1)),axis=1)`

Comment: hmmm interesting, I just get a large error when running that ends with   TypeError: Could not operate 10 with block values must be str, not int

Comment: got it too work! one of the columns had a bug in it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = [str(x) for x in range(1,8)]

df[cols] =  df[cols].add(5)
```

Here,

```
df[cols]
```

will select the columns from 1 to 7. String conversion is required as they are of dtype=object.

The code below will replace those columns with the increment of 5 within the same dataframe.

```
df[cols].add(5)
```